# How can I switch my already installed project to drupal-project?

Tags: composer

I am trying to make my already installed drupal site to use [drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project).

Answer (score 1):

Drupal project just helps you setup a project. But you can just take a look at the project on Github and copy/paste files/folders to your project.

Or you could initiate a new drupal-project and move over your custom modules/themes and make your new project use the database of the old one.